# Uneven tabling performance in BProlog 8.1

Tags: performance, prolog, memoization, b-prolog, prolog-tabling

I did a few experiments with the tabling capabilities of 
[b-prolog](/questions/tagged/b-prolog) version 8.1 and was quite surprised by the performance I observed.

Here is the code that I used. It counts the number of [Collatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) steps `N` required for reducing some positive integer `I` down to `1`:

```
%:- table posInt_CollatzSteps/2.               % remove comment to enable tabling
posInt_CollatzSteps(I,N) :-
   (  I == 1
   -> N = 0                                                % base case
   ;  1 is I /\ 1 
   -> I0 is I*3+1, posInt_CollatzSteps(I0,N0), N is N0+1   % odd
   ;  I0 is I>>1,  posInt_CollatzSteps(I0,N0), N is N0+1   % even
   ).
```

To determine the maximum number of reduction steps required for all integers from `I0` to `I`:

```
i0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(I0,I,M0,M) :-
   (  I0 > I
   -> M0 = M
   ;  posInt_CollatzSteps(I0,N0),
      I1 is I0+1,
      M1 is max(M0,N0),
      i0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(I1,I,M1,M)
   ).
```

When I ran some queries `?- time(i0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(1,1000000,0,MaxSteps)).` without and with tabling, I observed the following runtimes (in seconds):

- w/o tabling: 6.784
- with tabling: 2.323, **19.78**, *3.089*, *3.084*, *3.081*

By adding `:- table posInt_CollatzSteps/2.` the queries got 2x faster. Still, I'm puzzled:

- The 2nd run is more than 5x slower than the 1st.
  Apparently most time is spend in GC. From the 3rd run onwards, the tabling variant is fast again.
- Warm runs (3rd, 4th,...) are *noticeably slower* than the cold (1st) run.

I wasn't expecting this! Contrast this with the runtime that I observed with [xsb](/questions/tagged/xsb) version 3.6.0:

- w/o tabling: 14.287
- with tabling: 1.829, **0.31**, **0.308**, **0.31**, **0.333**

What can I do? Are there any directives or flags to help me get better performance with BProlog? I use BProlog version 8.1 64-bit edition with Linux.

Comment: Wont work with B-Prolog on Windows. Do you set the memory in some way? I even get: `?- i0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(1,100000,0,R).
*** error(resource_error(out_of_memory),stack_heap)`

Comment: Similar question in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404821/memoization-efficiency-problems-collatz-hailstone-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was checking against Jekejeke Prolog trailed memoing. Was only going
to n=100'000. For B-Prolog the following command line worked fine
on windows:

```
bp -s 40000000
```

This is said to amount to a stack/heap space of 160MB. I get both
tabled and non-tabled better warm runs than cold runs:

> B-Prolog n=100'000 in s:
>   w/o tabling: 14.276, 12.229
>   with tabling: 0.419, 0.143, 0.127, 0.152

The memoing [code](https://gist.github.com/jburse/b38ce92b7e73b4b8c605ef1d743c528a#file-collatz_j2-p) for Jekejeke uses the predicate assumez/2 from the
module hypo. In contrast to B-Prolog tabling, the trailed memoing will recalculate everything upon each call. You need to manually add it to your code:

> Jekejeke Prolog/Minlog n=100'000 in s:
>   w/o memoing: 4.521, 3.893
>   with memoing: 0.724, 0.573, 0.585, 0.555

So there is still room for speed improvements in Jekejeke. 
Concerning your B-Prolog question: When the memory is too
tight, this might irregularily put additional pressure on 
a GC, maybe resulting in your observed behaviour.

Bye

P.S.: This is the Jekejeke Prolog memoing code. You need to
install Jekejeke Minlog to have the module [hypo](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/docs/15_min/10_docu/02_reference/07_theory/01_minimal/02_hypo.html) available. Best 
is to install the latest release:

```
:- thread_local posInt_CollatzStepsm/2.

mposInt_CollatzSteps(I,N) :-
   (  I == 1
   -> N = 0                                                % base case
   ;  posInt_CollatzStepsm(I,N) %%% memo check
   -> true
   ;  1 is I /\ 1
   -> I0 is I*3+1, mposInt_CollatzSteps(I0,N0), N is N0+1,   % odd
      assumez(posInt_CollatzStepsm(I,N)) %%% memo add
   ;  I0 is I>>1,  mposInt_CollatzSteps(I0,N0), N is N0+1,   % even
      assumez(posInt_CollatzStepsm(I,N)) %%% memo add
   ).

?- time(mi0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(1, 100000, 0, R)).
% Up 724 ms, GC 71 ms, Thread Cpu 640 ms (Current 06/20/19 09:43:24)
R = 350

?- time(mi0_i_maxSteps0_maxSteps(1, 100000, 0, R)).
% Up 573 ms, GC 69 ms, Thread Cpu 500 ms (Current 06/20/19 09:43:27)
R = 350
```