# Dealing with complicated prolog loops

Tags: prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

I am using Prolog to encode some fairly complicated rules in a project of mine.  There is a lot of recursion, including mutual recursion.  Part of the rules look something like this:

```
pred1(X) :- ...
pred1(X) :- someguard(X), pred2(X).

pred2(X) :- ...
pred2(X) :- othercondition(X), pred1(X).
```

There is a fairly obvious infinite loop between `pred1` and `pred2`.  Unfortunately, the interaction between these predicates is very complicated and difficult to isolate.  I was able to eliminate the infinite loop in this instance by passing around a list of objects that have been passed to `pred1`, but this is extremely unwieldy!  In fact, it largely defeats the purpose of using Prolog in this application.

How can I make Prolog avoid infinite loops?  For example, if in the course of proving `pred1(foo)` it tries to prove `pred1(foo)` as a sub-goal, fail and backtrack.

Is it possible to do this with [meta-interpreters](http://www.metalevel.at/acomip/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One feature that is available in some Prolog systems and that may help you to solve such issues is called *tabling*. See for example the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028830/bounded-tabling) and [prolog-tabling](/questions/tagged/prolog-tabling).

If tabling is not available, then yes, meta-interpreters can definitely help a lot with this. For example, you can change the executation strategy etc. with a meta-interpreter.

In SWI-Prolog, also check out [`call_with_inference_limit/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call_with_inference_limit/3) to robustly limit the execution, independent of CPU type and system load.

Related and also useful are *termination analyzers* like [cTI](http://www.cs.unipr.it/cTI/): They allow you to statically derive *termination conditions*.

Comment: Thanks! Tabling is exactly what I needed.  cTI looks useful too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use meta-interpreters for this purpose, as mat suggests. But for the normal use case, that is going far beyond the regular effort.

What you may consider instead is to separate the looping functionality from your actual logic using higher-order predicates. That is a very safe way to go — SWI even checks if all the uses have a corresponding definition.  This checking is either invoked when typing `make.` or `check.`

As an example, consider [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133) and [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) which both handle loop checks "once and forever".